# Zoom and Pan in GMap.net

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, multi-touch, gmap.net

I'm trying to make [GMap.Net](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) control multitouch enabled, using WPF build-in events but i wasn't successful.

I found a series of articles about multitouch like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/11/04/introduction-to-wpf-4-multitouch.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansont/archive/2010/01/11/multi-touch-in-wpf-4-part-3-manipulation-events.aspx) one. In all of them, `ManipulationContainer` is a canvas and movable controls placed on it, but in GMap issue `ManipulationContainer` is `GMapControl` and there is no control over it. how can i use `e.ManipulationDelta` data to Zoom and Move?

The `GMapControl` has a `Zoom` property which by increase or decreasing it, you can zoom in or zoom out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at the code shows that the [`GMapControl` is an `ItemsContainer`](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f3ac356fa16e#GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation%2fGMap.NET.WindowsPresentation%2fGMapControl.cs).

You should be able to restyle the `ItemsPanel` template and supply the `IsManipulationEnabled` property there:

```
<g:GMapControl x:Name="Map" ...>
   <g:GMapControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <Canvas IsManipulationEnabled="True" />
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </g:GMapControl.ItemsPanel>
   <!-- ... -->
```

At this point you need to wire up the `Window`:

```
<Window ...
    ManipulationStarting="Window_ManipulationStarting"
    ManipulationDelta="Window_ManipulationDelta"
    ManipulationInertiaStarting="Window_InertiaStarting">
```

And supply the appropriate methods in the Code Behind (shamelessly stolen and adapted from this [MSDN Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649090.aspx)):

```
void Window_ManipulationStarting(
    object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
{
    e.ManipulationContainer = this;
    e.Handled = true;
}

void Window_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    // uses the scaling value to supply the Zoom amount
    this.Map.Zoom = e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;
    e.Handled = true;
}

void Window_InertiaStarting(
    object sender, ManipulationInertiaStartingEventArgs e)
{
    // Decrease the velocity of the Rectangle's resizing by 
    // 0.1 inches per second every second.
    // (0.1 inches * 96 pixels per inch / (1000ms^2)
    e.ExpansionBehavior.DesiredDeceleration = 0.1 * 96 / (1000.0 * 1000.0);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```