# Panning GMap.Net in Touch Screen Not working

Tags: wpf, gmap.net

With respect to the stack link:-

[Zoom and Pan in GMap.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502378/zoom-and-pan-in-gmap-net)

I have tried to pan the google map using the touch.

But, the panning is not working.

May I kindly know, how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the default drag button for GMap.net is the right mouse button. Try using:

```
gMapControl1.DragButton = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left;
```

when initializing.